# Django admin nested models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have model model `Word` which has foreign key to model `Group`
And I want the structure in django admin panel to be nested, like this:

```
-Group
 -Word1 (clickable where I can show all the info about this word model)
 -Word2 (clickable)
 -Word3 (clickable)
```

I tried to do something like this in admin.py but got an error: no class meta

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main_app.models import Profile, Project, User, Word, Phrase, Group

def unbound_callable(word):
    return word.name

class WordInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Word
    fields = ('name', 'model_callable', 'model_admin_callable', unbound_callable)
    readonly_fields = ('model_callable', 'model_admin_callable', unbound_callable)

    def model_admin_callable(self, word):
        return word.name

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Group
    inlines = (Word,)
    class Meta:
        model = Group

admin.site.register([GroupAdmin, Word, Phrase])
```

Answer (score 0):

`register()` method takes as first argrument list of models, but you passed admin class `GroupAdmin` there. You can use `register()` decorator with `GroupAdmin` instead. And register `Word` and `Phrase` models separately:

```
@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (Word,)

admin.site.register([Word, Phrase])
```

Note you don't need to specify `model = Group` inside `ModelAdmin` class.